# Only one specific ethernet wire giving stable connection

Tags: internet, ethernet

I was sharing a room and used my friend's ethernet wire and it was working perfectly fine. Since he moved, I bought two new ethernet wires and both aren't working Although it shows the connection, Internet does not come for long time and then after coming, goes away in 2 seconds with the same lan port(they both worked the first day fine, this problem started from the second day) . I again tried my friend's ethernet wire, and it was still working fine. My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 lts. This is so bizarre a problem, I wasn't able to find a solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Avinash welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is it possible you're using a [crossover](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-742ca3ffe527a79658f72c1f324088d0) cable? Check that the wires are in the same order on both ends.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail at the time. But after waking up it is temporarily fixed, don't know if it is permanent or not.